# Allow procedure to get multiple (but not defined) number of input variables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, json

I have a serie of statements like this one:

```
SELECT `Article`.`id`, `Article`.`title`,
CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN (`junction_article_author`.`authorRank` IS NULL AND `Authors`.`firstName` IS NULL AND `Authors`.`lastName` IS NULL AND `Authors`.`mononym` IS NULL AND `Authors`.`code` IS NULL AND `Authors`.`url` IS NULL) THEN
        NULL
    ELSE
        JSON_OBJECT(
            "rank", `junction_article_author`.`authorRank`,
            "firstName", `Authors`.`firstName`,
            "lastName", `Authors`.`lastName`,
            "mononym", `Authors`.`mononym`,
            "code", `Authors`.`code`,
            "url", `Authors`.`url`
        )
    END
), ']')  as authors,


CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN (`junction_article_keywords`.`keywordRank` IS NULL AND `Keywords`.`Name` IS NULL AND `Keywords`.`code` IS NULL) THEN
        NULL
    ELSE
        JSON_OBJECT(
    "rank", `junction_article_keywords`.`keywordRank`,
    "name", `Keywords`.`Name`,
    "code", `Keywords`.`code`
        )
    END
), ']') as keywords


FROM `Articles`;
```

In this statements, I have many rows formated with the `CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT […]` syntax . The goal of this syntax is to produce json after testing if the values of the given rows are not NULL.

BTW, as the syntax is pretty the same, I want to put it in a procedure and reuse it as much as I need it.

Then, the above statement will be something like this:

```
SELECT `Article`.`id`, `Article`.`title`,
makeConcatanatedJson(
            "rank", `junction_article_author`.`authorRank`,
            "firstName", `Authors`.`firstName`,
            "lastName", `Authors`.`lastName`,
            "mononym", `Authors`.`mononym`,
            "code", `Authors`.`code`,
            "url", `Authors`.`url`
)  as authors,


makeConcatanatedJson(
    "rank", `junction_article_keywords`.`keywordRank`,
    "name", `Keywords`.`Name`,
    "code", `Keywords`.`code`
) as keywords

FROM `Articles`;
```

But, as you see, the number of given parameters is not known in advance. So is their a way to give a kind of tuple and foreach inside it?